# Submit job to multiple hosts in grid-engine

Tags: sungridengine

in our lab some machines' disk I/O is down so if I submit my job to that machine, I can't get it done.
However, I can submit them to machines A and B.
I tried

```
qsub -l hostname=A,B
```

But that don't work, it looks like it only allows one hostname(hostname=A)
Is there a workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a wildcard expression; if you want to use A and B hosts :

```
qsub -l -h='(A|B)'
```